# Writing Thread Safe PHP extensions in Visual C++ for PHP8.2.8

Tags: php, visual-c++, php-extension

I am trying - and failing - to produce a Thread Safe PHP extension DLL.

I use PHP in a WAMP environment and code with both C++ and PHP. Now, I'm just trying to develop my first PHP extension (Module) in Visual C++, but have reached a brick wall.

Maybe someone can help?

I'm completely stumped, so any positive advice or assistance gratefully received.

I'm running **PHP 8.2.8 TS 64-bit** through an **Apache 2.4.x** web server on Windows Server
I'm using:
Visual Studio 2022 using Windows SDK 10 and the same platform API as the PHP (API20220829)

Preprocessor definitions: **ZEND_THREAD_SAFE; ZEND_WIN32; PHP_WIN32**
Linked to: **php8ts.php**

Language Standard: ISO C++ 14

Runtime Library: **Multi-threaded DLL (/MD)**

It compiles, links and dlivers the php_helloworld.dll

I have chosen every option I can to produce a THREAD SAFE version and I am using the downloaded PHP8.2.8 TS 64-bit TS development pack. ( **php-devel-pack-8.2.8-Win32-vs16-x64** ).

However, I get the following error every time, telling me it is **NON THREAD SAFE**.

PHP Warning: PHP Startup: php_helloworld: Unable to initialize module:

Module compiled with build ID=API20220829,**NTS**,VS16

PHP compiled with build ID=API20220829,**TS**,VS16

I have tried changes and tweaks to the configuration for 3 days and always the same result.

It is a very simple, single CPP file with following code, just to test it out:

```
// dllmain.cpp : Defines the entry point for the DLL application.
#include "pch.h"
#include "php.h"

#define ZEND_DEBUG 0

// Declare the function
PHP_FUNCTION(php_helloworld);

// register our function to the PHP API
// so that PHP knows, which functions are in this module
zend_function_entry php_helloworld_functions[] =
{
PHP_FE(php_helloworld, NULL)
{
NULL, NULL, NULL
}
};

// some pieces of information about our module
zend_module_entry php_helloworld_module_entry =
{
STANDARD_MODULE_HEADER,
"php_helloworld", // Extension name
php_helloworld_functions, // Function entry
NULL, // Module initialization
NULL, // Module shutdown
NULL, // Request initialization (not used)
NULL, // Request shutdown (not used)
NULL, // Extension info (not used)
"1.0", // Extension version
STANDARD_MODULE_PROPERTIES
};

// use a macro to output additional C code, to make ext dynamically loadable
ZEND_GET_MODULE(php_helloworld)

// Finally, we implement our "Hello World" function
// this function will be made available to PHP
// and prints to PHP stdout using printf
PHP_FUNCTION(php_helloworld)
{
php_printf("Hello World! (from our extension)\n");
}
```

Comment: Your problem is a compilation problem. Did you set `/D ZTS=1`? Show how you are building the extension. Please remove all the commentary about how hard you tried. That just clutters your question and takes longer to figure out what you are asking. State the problem, the error, etc. My guess is that you are building the extension using Visual Studio IDE instead of using the PHP SDK tools. Use the PHP SDK to build your extension. Then you can examine the command line flags to configure the IDE.